# PHP, How can I expand my code to check if the given location is not included in the database?

Tags: php, mysql

It works well to get data from the exist location, but not check the errors.

```
class Information extends DB {
function get(){
$loc=$_GET['loc'];
  return $this->select("SELECT location, MAX(population), MAX(total_deaths_per_million),  MAX(total_cases), MAX(total_deaths), MAX(total_cases_per_million) FROM corona WHERE location= '$loc'");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could run a query for just the location first. I haven't ran this to test it, but something like this should do the trick

```
class Information extends DB {
function get(){
$loc=$_GET['loc'];    

$locationResults = $this->select("SELECT location FROM corona WHERE location= '$loc'");

if ($locationResults->num_rows == 0) {
    echo "If the number of rows returned is equal to 0, then there's no locations for the location the user gave";      
    } else {
       return $this->select("SELECT location, MAX(population), MAX(total_deaths_per_million),  MAX(total_cases), MAX(total_deaths), MAX(total_cases_per_million) FROM corona WHERE location= '$loc'");

    }// end else
  }//end function
}//end class
```

Comment: I think this gonna work, but I have another problem.
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

`$list = new Reszlet();

if (is_array($list) || is_object($list)){
  foreach ($list->get() as $l) {
    echo '<div id="infoboxes">
        <h1>'.$l['location'].'</h1>
      <div class="infobox">
        <h2>Total Cases</h2>
        <h3>'.$l['MAX(total_cases)'].'</h3>
      </div>`